# Meteor: multiple calls to async server method

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor

I need to call 3 times the same server method with different parameters:

```
  // client code
  var types = ['type1', 'type2', 'type3'];
  for (var i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
    console.log('client calling', types[i])
    Meteor.call('myMethod', types[i], function (error, result) {
      console.log('client got', types[i])
      Session.set(types[i], result.data);
    });
  }

  // server code
  var Future = Npm.require("fibers/future");

  Meteor.methods({
    myMethod: function (type) {
      var params = {
        type: type
      };

      var future = new Future();
      console.log('server calling', type)
      HTTP.call("GET", Meteor.App.HOST + "/myApi",
        {params: params}, function (error, results) {
          if (error) {
            future.throw(error);
          } else {
            console.log('server got', type)
            future.return(results);
          }
        });

      return future.wait();
    }
  });
```

The server HTTP call takes up to 10 seconds. Looking at the logs I see:

```
// client
client calling type1
client calling type2
client calling type3
client got type1
client got type2
client got type3

// server
server calling type1
server got type1
server calling type2
server got type2
server calling type3
server got type3
```

The client logs are OK. I would expect the same behaviour on the server but it seems that the calls made by one client are executed sequentially. If I start two clients I have the following server logs:

```
// server
server calling type1
server calling type1
server got type1
server calling type2
server got type1
server calling type2
server got type2
server calling type3
server got type2
server calling type3
server got type3
server got type3
```

Is this a limitation or my code is not correct?

Comment: Looks like normal async behavior. Why do you think this is not correct? What behavior are you expecting? Even in your single client case the results from Meteor.call() could come back out of order if one of the HTTP GETs takes a long time. By the way, why are you calling your own server with HTTP GET?

Comment: @Fabrizio you need to use inside meteor method `this.unblock()` http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/method_unblock

Comment: @MarkUretsky Thanks a lot! `this.unblock()` is exactly what I need.

Comment: @FabrizioFortino no problem, I will add it as answer if case of anyone needing this information as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.unblock()` inside a method call will solve this problem, it will not block the meteor method it's good when you do some API calls, sending Emails and don't really have to wait for it to finish

> Call inside a method invocation. Allow subsequent method from this
>   client to begin running in a new fiber.
>   http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/method_unblock